converting safe.tensor to pytorch bin files
I fine-tuned my transformer model with HuggingFace. It has provided me a model.safetensor file for later use.
I want to plug-in the model to a old framework which takes pytorch.bin files only. I wonder how can I downgrade my model to fit the framework.
I am not sure what is the best way to do such moodel format conversion.
Thanks for your help.

This question is similar to: Model.save_pretrained is not saving .bin files. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You will get a model in .safetensors format if you save the model using the following code:
model.save_pretrained('folder/').
And you will get a .bin format model if you save the model using the following code:
torch.save(model.state_dict(),'folder/pytorch_model.bin'.format(epoch)).
Alternatively, you can use
model.save_pretrained(output_dir, safe_serialization=False).
When you downgrade the transformers library, it will automatically save the model in a .bin file.

downgrade to what? A complete example answering the question would be nice where given a model.safetensors file we end up with pytorch.bin
